# search for users age based on date of birth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, date

I am having trouble understanding how to perform a range search of a users age based on their date of birth. My DB stores the user dob only. I want for visitors to use the advanced search form and perform age searches such as '18-23', '28-36', etc.

I have tried a few things but none seem to work. I added scope to User model, def min & max age, and one other solution that did not pan out. Maybe I am getting some of the code right but not executing the other part. I am not sure. If someone can guide me the right direction that would be great so I can learn this.

When I perform a search based on selected age it returns all users.

Search Model:

```
attr_accessible :age, :children, :ethnicity, :career, :gender, :religion, :zip_code, :birthday, :max_age, :min_age, :youngest_age, :oldest_age

  def users
    @users ||= find_users
  end

    private

  def find_users
    users = User.order(:id)
    users = users.where(gender: gender) if gender.present?
       users = users.where(zip_code: zip_code) if zip_code.present?
       users = users.where(children: children) if children.present?
       users = users.where(religion: religion) if religion.present?
       users = users.where(ethnicity: ethnicity) if ethnicity.present?
       users = users.where("birthday >= ? AND birthday <= ?", 80.years.ago + 1.day, 18.years.ago)


       users
  end
end
```

Search_Form:

```
<%= select(@object, :youngest_age, (18..75).to_a) %> to <%= select(@object, :oldest_age, (18..75).to_a) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
# view
<%= select @object, :min_age, (18..75).to_a %>
to
<%= select @object, :max_age, (18..75).to_a %>

# controller
def show
  @search = Search.find(params[:id])
  @users = @search.users
end

# Search model
def find_users
  users = User.order(:id)
  users = users.where(gender: gender) if gender.present?
  users = users.where(zip_code: zip_code) if zip_code.present?
  users = users.where(children: children) if children.present?
  users = users.where(religion: religion) if religion.present?
  users = users.where(ethnicity: ethnicity) if ethnicity.present?

  if min_age.present? && max_age.present?
    min = [ min_age, max_age ].min
    max = [ min_age, max_age ].max
    min_date = Date.today - min.years
    max_date = Date.today - max.years
    users = users.where("birthday BETWEEN ? AND ?", max_date, min_date)
  end
  users
end
```

Comment: I am saving searches to the database which is why the model is there.

Comment: Then you can use the code of the search method as the find_users method on the Search model -- I just updated my answer @pwz2000

Comment: I receive a undefined local variable or method min_age that points to the search model from line `if min_age.present ? && max_age.present?`. It also is showing from search model under def users `@users ||=find_users` and search controller for def show `@users = @search.users`.

Comment: You have to make these attributes accessible. Does your Search model has these 2 attributes (min_age and max_age)?

Comment: Yes, those have been there.   `attr_accessible :age, :children, :ethnicity, :career, :gender, :religion, :zip_code, :birthday, :max_age, :min_age, :youngest_age, :oldest_age`

Comment: Then it's weird you get this error message, there is something wrong with your Search model. Try to find the glitch using the rails console, creating Search object directly from there and see if they all are instanciated correctly and have the proper attributes

Comment: One issue could be the search table does not have a min_age or max_age column. It has 'age' for column which is not in use. I edited some code so that I don't receive the error, and of course the age is returning NULL.

Comment: yess you have to add these 2 attributes on the search model if you want to use it in the search conditions. -- You might want to serialize the search conditions into a Hash in your DB instead of having X columns for each attribute you want to search on. If you are interested let me know and I'll find you some examples ;-)

Comment: I added the two columns. It now returns all users since the new columns are reading NULL.

Comment: Then populate the database with proper data! Create a search object with relevant values for max_age and min_age !!

Comment: Also keep in mind that 
`users.where("birthday BETWEEN ? AND ?", max_date, min_date)`
 can be written as
`users.where(birthday: min_date..max_date)`

Comment: Even with populating the database for min and max age it returns all users. The search table still shows NULL for the columns. This is the same issue I had prior coming to Stack. There has been a small issue with my coding, and I don't think it has anything to do with the Search model. I will continue to check my code to see if I am missing something or misspelled anything wrong.

Comment: @pwz2000 can you please update the question with the latest state of your code?

Comment: @j03w code has been updated. I'm starting to think it's a issue with the database which is why it is returning all users.

Comment: @pwz2000 I don't know why you have a search model because the query will be executed each time you try to show a Seach object. If you want to keep a trace of each searches, I understand the need for the Search model, but if not, you can achieve this user retrieving way more easily

Comment: The issue was in the show. It should've been `<%= f.select :min_age, (18..99) %>`. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: The only issue is if you do a 1 year difference in the age search. For example User A is 25 years old and User B is 26 years old. You performed a search for 25-26 and the results will only return User A. The only way I can get User B in the results is if I go a year over and do a 25-27 search.

Comment: Use this instead: `where("birthday >= ? AND birthday <= ?", max_date, min_date)`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass back two parameters from your search form to your controller. I'm assuming those will be `params[:youngest_age]` and `params[:oldest_age]` for this. I'm also assuming those will be integers (ex: `params[:youngest_age] = 18`)

```
youngest_age = params[:youngest_age].years
oldest_age = params[:oldest_age].years

User.where("birthday >= ? AND birthday <= ?", Date.today - youngest_age, Date.today - oldest_age)
```

Comment: I am getting the same error 'undefined local variable or method `min_age'' that points to search model. I have updated my code with what I have.

Comment: It sounds like you're dealing with an issue in your models / controller that is separate from fetching users who are in the age range given.  Are you getting an error when rendering the form (new action) or when you submit it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a bug in your code in this method:

```
def find_users
  users = User.order(:id)
  users = users.where(gender: gender) if gender.present?
  users = users.where(zip_code: zip_code) if zip_code.present?
  users = users.where(children: children) if children.present?
  users = users.where(religion: religion) if religion.present?
  users = users.where(ethnicity: ethnicity) if ethnicity.present?
  users = User.where("birthday >= ? AND birthday <= ?", 80.years.ago + 1.day, 18.years.ago)
  users
end
```

On the second to last line, just before you return users, you call "User.where" rather than "users.where". So essentially you're starting a new query at that point rather than adding all the conditions together.

Comment: Switching to users.where does not change anything.

Comment: I could just have a issue with the database. I have been at work on the code itself for quite some time and nobody has really suggested anything I haven't tried. The only part I have not taken a deeper look at was the data in the database.

Comment: Thanks for assisting. MrYoshiji provided a solution that worked and I had to fix the view.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the last `where` clause of your `find_users` method to use the `users` relation so you continue the query chain instead of the `User` model class which effectively resets the query scope.

For date range search your query could avoid SQL string fragments completely using a regular ruby range:

User Model:

```
def self.with_age_range(year_range)
  today = Date.today
  where birthday: (today - year_range.max.years)..(today - year_range.min.years)
end
```

And call it as follows:

```
User.with_age_range 18..23
```

Or in your controller:

```
@users = User.with_age_range params[:min_age]..params[:max_age]
```

Comment: 'Undefined method yeas for nil:NilClass' for the User model with the code you created. Specifically the `where birthday: (today - year_range.max.years)..(today - year_range.min.years)`

Comment: I have the answer thanks to MrYoshiji. And I also needed to do a small fix with the view. Thanks for posting!