# search for user age based on date of birth

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie in Ruby on Rails and i am following this post:
[search for users age based on date of birth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236607/search-for-users-age-based-on-date-of-birth)
My application has many users and each user has one profile. For each profile in my db, I save their first name, last name , country and their date of birth(type:date). I want my users have the ability to search and find other users based on their range age like from '25-35' or '35-45. My searches for first name, last name and country works fine but when I search for their age, search returns all profiles and it doesn't perform any search.

I have spent couple of days on this and can't figure out what is the problem. Here is my code:

View:searches/new.html.haml

```
  %h1 Custome Search

  =form_for @search do |form|
    =form.label :first_name
    %br/
    = form.text_field :first_name 
    %br/
    
    =form.label :last_name
    %br/
    = form.text_field :last_name 
    %br/
        
    =form.label :country
    %br/
    =form.select :country, options_for_select([['Norway',0], ['Sweden',1],['USA',3]]),{include_blank: true}
    %br/
    %br/
    from
    =select @search, :min_age, (18..75).to_a 
    to 
    =select @search, :max_age, (18..75).to_a

    -#from
    -#=form.select :min_age, (18..75).to_a ,{include_blank: true}
    -#to 
    -#=form.select :max_age, (18..75).to_a,{include_blank: true}  

    = form.submit "search"
```

Model: search.rb

```
class Search < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :min_age, :max_age

  def search_profiles
    profiles= Profile.all
    profiles=profiles.where(["first_name LIKE ?","%#{first_name}%"]) if first_name.present?
    profiles=profiles.where(["last_name LIKE ?","%#{last_name}%"]) if last_name.present?    
    profiles=profiles.where(["country LIKE ?","#{country}"]) if country.present?
    if min_age.present? && max_age.present?
      min = [ min_age, max_age ].min
      max = [ min_age, max_age ].max
      min_date = Date.today - min.years
      max_date = Date.today - max.years  
      profiles = profiles.where("date_of_birth BETWEEN ? AND ?", max_date, min_date)
    end  

    return profiles
    
  end
  
end
```

Searches controller:

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  attr_accessor :min_age, :max_age

  def new
    @search = Search.new
  end
  def create
    @search=Search.create(search_params)
    redirect_to @search
  end

  def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
  end
  private
  def search_params
    params.require(:search).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :country, :date_of_birth,:min_age, :max_age)
  end

end
like so
```

Model: profile.rb

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  enum country: [:Norway, :Sweden, :USA]
  validates :first_name,:last_name,:date_of_birth,:country,:min_age,:max_age, presence: true
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessor :min_age, :max_age 

end
like so
```

View: form.html.haml

```
= form_with(model: profile) do |form|
  - if profile.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2
        = pluralize(profile.errors.count, "error")
        prohibited this profile from being saved:
      %ul
        - profile.errors.each do |error|
          %li= error.full_message
  .field
    = form.label :first_name
    = form.text_field :first_name
  .field
    = form.label :last_name
    = form.text_field :last_name
  .field
    = form.label :date_of_birth
    = form.date_select :date_of_birth,{start_year: 1940, end_year: Time.now.year - 18}
  .field
    = form.label :country
    = form.select :country, Profile.countries.keys.to_a,{include_blank: "Selct your country"}
  .field
    = form.label :image
    = form.file_field :image
  .actions
    = form.submit
```

Profiles.controller:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile, only: [ :show, :edit, :update, :destroy ]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except:[:index, :show, :search]
   

  def index
    @profiles = Profile.all
  end

  def show
  
  end

  # GET /profiles/new
  def new
    @profile = current_user.build_profile
  end

  # GET /profiles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  def create
    
      @profile = current_user.build_profile(profile_params)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @profile.save
          format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: "Profile was successfully created." }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @profile }
        else
          format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: "Profile was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /profiles/1 or /profiles/1.json
  def destroy
    @profile.destroy
      redirect_to profiles_url, notice: "Profile was successfully destroyed." 
  end

  private
    def set_profile
      @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    end

    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name,:country, :image, :date_of_birth,:min_age, :max_age)
    end
      
end
```

Comment: Have you done some basic debugging on this, like putting `byebug` in the search method to see if `min_age` is actually some value?

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner, I am not ye familar with byebug. Don't I pass a value to min_age in drop down menu of my new.html.haml file?

Comment: Are you missing `form` in front of your `select`?

Comment: First I tried with form.select but I didn't get any result, as you can see I have commented that part of the code which has form.select.

Comment: On Postgres you can use `.where("EXCTRACT('year', AGE(profilles.date_of_birth)) BETWEEN ? AND ?" min_age, max_age)`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-datetime.html

Comment: @max I get syntax error on but i don't see an error!      profiles = profiles.where("EXCTRACT('year', AGE(profiles.date_of_birth)) BETWEEN ? AND ?" min_age, max_age)

Comment: Oops I wrote it on my phone and  missed a comma. `profiles = profiles.where("EXCTRACT('year', AGE(profiles.date_of_birth)) BETWEEN ? AND ?", min_age, max_age)`.

Comment: @max, thanks, now I don't get the syntax error but nothing happens, it shows all the profiles. In my rails s in command prompt i can see when I search for country, the country is inserted into searches but  min_age and max_age are not inserted in the searches!